# Margin not working on div to create gap between header and content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a gap between the header (image + navigation bar) and the content part (white box below navogation bar). With margin/padding on several places it does increase the space in top of the white box, but doesn't create a transparent gap where I can see the background image.

The header with id=branding is pushed with

```
#branding {
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

to the bottom, therefore it creates the gap on the top of the page. When I try to add a `margin-bottom: 30px;` to this CSS it increases the space on the top of the white box.

The page I'm working on is [this](http://www.muratdiril.at/new).
The page is based on a template, therefore I'm not 100% sure what I should insert here as code parts!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, try to set background-color of the wrapper as transparent

```
.wrapper {
 background-color: transparent;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

And then add background-color to header and content, now you can add margin bottom to the header or margin top to the content.

```
 #branding {
 margin-top: 30px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 }

 .container {
   margin: 5% auto;
   max-width: 978px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

After that you could see the background image of your site.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

To your website have a gap you have to make a few change to your CSS.

On the `.wrapper` remove the background. Then on `.header-image` add yuor pixel value.

```
.header-image{
  margin-bottom: your pixel value;
}
```

Then #main put `background-color: #fff`; and add `padding: 50px 10px 50px;`

```
#main{
  background-color: #fff
  padding: 50px 10px 50px;
}
```

Finally take off the width off of `.container`.

Next time put your code here in SO for people do not have to go look at your website.